# C++ basic program segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, g++

here is my CPP program

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
     return 0;
}
```

compiling and executing this, causes a seg fault:

```
[18:08 ~] > g++ test.cpp
[18:09 ~] > ./a.out
Segmentation fault
```

Does anybody have an idea about this issue please? 
Thanks a lot for your help.

Here are some details that might be useful:

```
[18:13 ~] > ldd a.out
 linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff3fdff000)
 libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.6/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fc8f4a53000)
 libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fc8f47ce000)
 libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fc8f45b8000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc8f4225000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc8f4ca5000)
```

and also gdb:

```
[18:15 ~] > gdb ./a.out
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.2-60.el6)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from ...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: a.out

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7bd48ec in std::ios_base::Init::Init() () from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.6/libstdc++.so.6
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.x86_64 libgcc-4.4.7-3.el6.x86_64
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7bd48ec in std::ios_base::Init::Init() () from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.6/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x0000000000400831 in __static_initialization_and_destruction_0 (__initialize_p=1, __priority=65535) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.6/../../../../include/c++/3.4.6/iostream:77
#2  0x0000000000400873 in global constructors keyed to main() () at test.cpp:7
#3  0x0000000000400976 in __do_global_ctors_aux ()
#4  0x00000000004005a3 in _init ()
#5  0x00007fffffffe448 in ?? ()
#6  0x0000000000400905 in __libc_csu_init ()
#7  0x00007ffff7385c70 in __libc_start_main () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#8  0x0000000000400659 in _start ()
(gdb)
```

g++

```
[10:14 ~] > g++ -v
Reading specs from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.6/specs
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --disable-checking --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-languages=c,c++,f77 --disable-libgcj --host=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-19.el6)
```

and last thing

```
[10:25 ~] > ls /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux
3.4.6
```

Thank you.

Comment: What version does g++ report? (`g++ -v`)

Comment: Hello Mat, thank you. I updated my first thread with more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So apparently your problem is that your g++ installation is broken.  I see from the messages that you have RHEL6, but somehow have version 3.4.6 of libstdc++.

My RHEL6 system has version 4.4.6 of gcc, libstdc++, etc.  I assume that this older version of libstdc++ is related to your problem.

What versions do you have installed of gcc, g++, and libstdc++?  From the other messages, it looks like you have 4.4.7, but do you happen to have multiple versions or mixed versions?

```
rpm -q gcc g++ libstdc++
```

Also, what other directories do you have under /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux?

```
ls /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux
```

Comment: Hello Russel, thank you. I updated my first thread with more details

Comment: My best guess at this point is that you have a mismatch between versions of g++ and libgcc and they are not compatible.  From the info you've provided so far, it looks like you have version 3.4.6 of g++ and libstdc++, but version 4.4.7 of libgcc.  I can't tell what version of gcc you have, but I suspect 4.4.7.  I would recommend upgrading g++ and libstdc++ so they match the version of gcc you have.  Unless gcc is also 3.4.6, and in that case you might just downgrade libgcc to match.

Comment: If getting the versions to all match up doesn't fix you up, I'd recommend going to the gcc mailing lists for help.

Answer (score 0):

i think that you miss something while installing g++

```
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.x86_64 libgcc-4.4.7-3.el6.x86_64
```